# Slack API rate limits: respecting Retry-After and still getting limited

Tags: slack-api

I'm calling the [Slack search.messages endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/search.messages) and getting HTTP 429 responses when I make too many calls. These responses come with a Retry-After header indicating the number of seconds to wait before retrying ([docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits)). I've set up my code to wait this number of seconds but I'm still rate-limited when I retry.

- I'm getting values from Slack for Retry-After in the range of 1 to 3 seconds
- I can confirm that I'm waiting that number of seconds, I'm not using milliseconds
- Only this process is accessing the Slack API while I'm testing
- I've tried waiting around 20 seconds instead of the 1-3 indicated and still get rate limited. Waiting 60 seconds seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong or are the values slack is sending incorrect?

Comment: I have not experiences this behavior when using the Slack API, but I think your best approach is to avoid getting into rate limiting in the first place. That method is Tier 2, so make sure you stay below 20 calls per minute and you should be golden.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had some incorrect assumptions and not enough logging. I hope that explaining this might help someone else.

The value returned in the Retry-After header is the number of seconds until at least one more request will succeed not until rate-limiting is 'reset'.

In my testing, after waiting for `Retry-After`seconds one request was succeeding (but not logged) before a second request was again rate-limited. This meant I only saw the wait time, and a request fail, leading me to believe `Retry-After` was not correct.